# How does one comment in an erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, erb, block-comments

I have some trivial markup that looks like the following:

```
<li class="someclass">
  <=% t'model.attr' %>
</li>
```

Is there a trivial way to comment that out? Just wrapping `<!-- -->` around the block will still leave the ruby code available to the template. This means I have to comment out the HTML and Ruby specific code separately.

What's the best way to comment out all three lines with the least amount of markup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`=begin` and `=end` are the Ruby version of block comments.

Using them in an erb template:

```
<%
=begin
%>
<li class="someclass">
  <=% t'model.attr' %>
</li>
<%
=end
%>
```

Comment: This does work, and it's the best way I've found, but doesn't it mean something semantically besides "comment this out?" I wish there were a more sanctioned way, if so.

Comment: `=begin` and `=end` are the Ruby version of block comments. Alternatively, you could also do `<<-ASDF` and `ASDF` (replacing ASDF with whatever keyword you want). This is the heredoc comment format.

Answer (score 12):

You can comment ERB blocks using `#`:

```
<!-- <li class="someclass"> -->
  <%#= t'model.attr' %>
<!-- </li> -->
```

or avoid the literal HTML using Rails `content_tag` method:

```
<%#= content_tag :li, t'model.attr', :class=>:someclass %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't work:

```
<%# <li class="someclass">
  <=% t'model.attr' %>
</li> %>
```

Does work:

```
<% if false %>
<li class="someclass">
  <=% t'model.attr' %>
</li>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: Coming over from Python/etc this syntax is easy to use and would be easier to read for a non Ruby person. A win in my book any day.

Answer (score 0):

Edited because I noticed the true intention of your question:

```
<%
=begin
%>
<li class="someclass">
  <%= t'model.attr' %>
</li>
<%
=end
%>
```

In every syntax highlighter that I've used (mainly textmate), this needs to be at the very beginning of the line, you can't indent it for it to appear commented. I don't know if that's a rule or a poor implementation of the highlighting.