# Why is this Capbara 'have_content' expectation unexpectedly passing?

Tags: ruby, capybara, acceptance-testing

I am trying to do some acceptance testing and confirm the presence of a model's various attributes being rendered on a Quote#show page. I am using code an expectation as below;

```
expect(page).to have_content("#{quote.industry}")
```

I am using FactoryGirl to `Quote.create` with required object attrs. `Quote.industry` is an `enum` created on the quote model with a range of options, all works and renders just fine. However wven when I comment out the diaplay of this attribute on the template the test still passes. There is no other element on the page that matches quote.industry. I cannot work out what's going on?

Secondary to actually understanding what's going on with the above, perhaps it' bad form to be interpolating a value into a Capybara matcher argument? Should one stick to giving strings to the `have_content` matcher?
But perhaps the argument given to have_content should just be a string, as opposed to an interpolated FactoryGirl object. Is this acceptable practice?

Thanks

quote_page_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'quote page' do
    scenario 'renders all quote attributes' do
        quote = FactoryGirl.create(:quote)
        visit("/quotes/#{quote.id}")

        expect(page).to have_content("#{quote.industry}")
    end
end
```

factories/quotes.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :quote do
    sequence(:co_name) { |n| "Acme Co #{n}" }
    industry Quote.industries[:financial_services]
  end
end
```

models/quote.rb

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
    enum industry:          [ :financial_services, :architect, :business_consultancy ]
    enum payment_frequency: [ :annually, :monthly ]
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Property</th>
              <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Company name</td>
              <td><%= @quote.co_name %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Company number</td>
              <td><%= @quote.co_number %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Office postcode</td>
              <td><%= @quote.postcode %></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- <tr>
              <td>Industry</td>
              <td><%= @quote.industry %></td>
            </tr> -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It shouldn't be passing, are you sure you actually saved the template when adding the comment?  You can output `page.html` before the expectation to see what the actual page source is.  Also check the string value of `quote.industry` since if it happens to be an empty string for some reason it would match everything.

Comment: aha, I now find that for some reason the actual attr is not saving to the db, see my question here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293291/why-some-model-attributes-not-saved-in-the-db. But that still doesn't solve why this test is passing. Indeed `quote.industry` is completely empty, so that test should not pass, yet is still does.

Comment: If it's completely empty it will pass -- have_content by default does substring matching and a completely empty string is a substring of anything.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, object was nil, so test was still passing, submit your comment as the answer and I will accept it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`have_content` matching (by default) does substring matching.  If `quote.industry` is nil it will get interpolated to an empty string which is a substring of any content on the page so the test will pass.

Answer (score -1):

The test still passes because the content is still there (check your page source). If you want to comment out the `erb` output you have to use the proper syntax which is:

```
<% =begin %>  
  <% my_code %>
<%=end %>
```

for multiline comments and

```
<%# my_code %>
```

for single lines.

This topic (I'm meaning comments, not tests) was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127644/block-comments-in-html-erb-templates-in-rails) and [here again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426671/how-does-one-comment-in-an-erb-template).

Comment: The whole `tr` is being commented out with an HTML comment, the fact that the string is in the source should be irrelevant

Comment: It should not, `have_content` checks your page for generated content and the content is being generated. BTW, wich version of capybara are you working with?

Comment: Actually, `have_content` checks for visible text on the page (it's just an alias for `have_text). HTML comments are not visible on the page, nor are the contents of them parsed as elements into the DOM, so when something is inside an HTML comment it should be irrelevant to Capybara.  That should be in all versions of Capybara  (I develop Capybara)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole: You're absolutely right, it filters everything not visible by the browser, even nodes with `display:none`, the tests should not be passing

Comment: Im using capybara (2.14.0)